# Animate threeJS light color with tweenmax

Tags: three.js, light, gsap

I would like to change my threeJS lights colors with a tweenmax timeline but it doesn't seems to work.
Here is kind of what I tried. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var light  = new THREE.HemisphereLight( "hsl(0,0%,87%);", 0xFFFFFF, 1);
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x69be94, 1, 15, 2 );
var light3 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFE0, 1, 30, Math.PI/14, 1 );

...

var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.to(light.color.setHSL, 1, { h : 1, s : 0.4, l : 0.58 });
tl.to(light2.color.setHex, 1, { hex: "#69BE94" });
tl.to(light3.color.setRGB, 1, { r: 105, g:190 ,b:148 }, 1,);
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `.setHSL, .setHex, & .setRGB` are [all methods](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.setHSL), AKA functions. You can't point to a method as the first argument of TweenMax, it has to be a property. You'll need to do something like this:

`tl.to(light3.color, 1, {r: 0.3, g:0.7, b:0.5}, 1,);` So the timeline can access it.

Also, keep in mind that color `.rgb` values [are in the `[0, 1]` range](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.r), not `[0, 255]`. If you need to tween to a specific HSL value, just use a temporary color variable:

```js
// Create temp variable to extract RGB values
var tempColor = new THREE.Color().setHSL(1, 0.4, 0.58);
tl.to(light.color, 1, { r: tempColor.r, g: tempColor.g, b: tempColor.b });

// Extract RGB values from tempColor again
tempColor.setHex(0x69BE94);
tl.to(light2.color, 1, { r: tempColor.r, g: tempColor.g, b: tempColor.b });
```

[.setHex takes an integer, not a string](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.setHex)

Answer (score 1):

@Marquizzo's answer works but if you actually want to tween HSL and not RGB then you need a different solution.

As pointed out tweenmax adjust properties so you can make an object that uses getters and setters so it has properties for tweenmax to adjust but ends up setting the color.

```
class HSLHelper {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.temp = {h: 0, s: 0, l: 0};
  }
  get h() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).h; }
  set h(h) {
    const {s, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get s() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).s; }
  set s(s) {
    const {h, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get l() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).l; }
  set l(l) {
    const {h, s} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
}
```

And now you can use it, example.

```
const p = new THREE.PointLight( 0x69be94, 1, 15, 2 );
const helper = new HSLHelper(p.color);

var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.to(helper, 1, { h : 1, s : 0.4, l : 0.58 });
```

Compare the results: the cube on the left is using RGB tweening, the cube on the right is using HSL tweening

```js
class HSLHelper {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.temp = {h: 0, s: 0, l: 0};
  }
  get h() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).h; }
  set h(h) {
    const {s, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get s() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).s; }
  set s(s) {
    const {h, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get l() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).l; }
  set l(l) {
    const {h, s} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
}

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

  const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
  scene.add(cube1);
  cube1.position.x = -1;
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
  scene.add(cube2);
  cube2.position.x = 1;


  const tl1 = new TimelineMax();
  tl1.fromTo(material1.color, {r: 1, g: 0, b: 0}, {duration: 2, r: 0, g: 0, b: 1, ease:Linear.easeNone});
  tl1.repeat(-1);
  
  const helper2 = new HSLHelper(material2.color);
  const tl2 = new TimelineMax();
  tl2.fromTo(helper2, {h: 0, s: 1, l: 0.5}, {duration: 2, h: 0.66, s: 1, l: 0.5, ease:Linear.easeNone});
  tl2.repeat(-1);
  
  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.0.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Also note that the H (hue) in HSL is unbounded 0 = red, 0.33 = green, 0.66 = blue, 1 = red, 1.33 = green, 1.66 = blue, etc.. So for example if I set h to go from 0 to 10 over 5 seconds it will go through all the colors 10 times over 5 seconds

```js
class HSLHelper {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.temp = {h: 0, s: 0, l: 0};
  }
  get h() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).h; }
  set h(h) {
    const {s, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get s() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).s; }
  set s(s) {
    const {h, l} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
  get l() { return this.color.getHSL(this.temp).l; }
  set l(l) {
    const {h, s} = this.color.getHSL(this.temp);
    this.color.setHSL(h, s, l);
  }
}

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

  const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
  scene.add(cube1);
  cube1.position.x = -1;
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
  scene.add(cube2);
  cube2.position.x = 1;


  const helper1 = new HSLHelper(material1.color);
  const tl1 = new TimelineMax();
  tl1.fromTo(helper1, {h: 0, s: 1, l: 0.5}, {duration: 5, h: 1, s: 1, l: 0.5, ease:Linear.easeNone});
  tl1.repeat(-1);
  
  const helper2 = new HSLHelper(material2.color);
  const tl2 = new TimelineMax();
  tl2.fromTo(helper2, {h: 0, s: 1, l: 0.5}, {duration: 5, h: 10, s: 1, l: 0.5, ease:Linear.easeNone});
  tl2.repeat(-1);
  
  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.0.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

While both Marquizzo and gman are in the right direction, it's actually even more simple in GSAP! You can just animate the `.color` to values that you set (it's easiest to use a new `THREE.Color` object). For example:

```
// The new colors in whatever format you want
const newColor1 = new THREE.Color("hsl(120, 100%, 50%)");
const newColor2 = new THREE.Color("blue");

const tl1 = gsap.timeline({repeat: -1});
tl1.to(material1.color, {duration: 5, r: newColor1.r, g: newColor1.g, b: newColor1.b, ease:"none"});

const tl2 = gsap.timeline({repeat: -1});
tl2.to(material2.color, {duration: 5, r: newColor2.r, g: newColor2.g, b: newColor2.b, ease:"none"});
```

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
  const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

  const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
  scene.add(cube1);
  cube1.position.x = -1;
  const cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
  scene.add(cube2);
  cube2.position.x = 1;


  // The new colors in whatever format you want
  const newColor1 = new THREE.Color("hsl(120, 100%, 50%)");
  const newColor2 = new THREE.Color("blue");

  const tl1 = gsap.timeline({repeat: -1});
  tl1.to(material1.color, {duration: 5, r: newColor1.r, g: newColor1.g, b: newColor1.b, ease:"none"});
  
  const tl2 = gsap.timeline({repeat: -1});
  tl2.to(material2.color, {duration: 5, r: newColor2.r, g: newColor2.g, b: newColor2.b, ease:"none"});
  
  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.2.1/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code is not tweening by HSL, it's only tweening by RGB. Compare: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/bpyw0f97/

Comment: @gman Correct. Given the OP never said they are looking for an HSL tween I think my answer is appropriate.

Comment: Your answer is not "even more simple" since it's not solvng the same problem.

Comment: @gman I don't understand what you're trying to argue. This approach is a more simple way to tween colors than the others provided. Given that's all that we know the OP wants to do I think my answer is valid. I upvoted both existing answers as they are both helpful. What's the problem?

Comment: I didn't suggest your answer isn't valid. I'm just saying it's not simpler because it's not solving the same issue. To put it concretely, if your first sentence didn't exist I wouldn't have commented. Instead you added a judgement that your solution is simpler and I'm just pointing out your solution does not do the same thing. Whether the OP cares or not I have no idea, I'm just making it clear that your first sentence doesn't tell the whole story in case the OP does care.